# Inside OneDrive; How I can stop syncing 3 document libraries and remove all the local copies without affecting the file on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, onedrive

I have synced 3 online document libraries using OneDrive, as follow:-

[image]

now I want to stop the sync and delete all the local files and the 3 folders from my PC.. but I do not want to delete those files and libraries from SharePoint.. so how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Please the following steps:**

- Click the **blue cloud icon** in the notification bar.

[image]

- Click "**Help & Settings**" and select "**Settings**"

[image]

- On the Microsoft OneDrive Dialog box, go to the "**Account**" tab. Please click "**Stop sync**" link that behind the syncing Document Library.

[image]

E.g: "Stop sync" --- "Echo - Documents" and remove "Echo - Documents" in the local File Explorer. You will find this is not affect the files/library on SharePoint.

[image]